# Printf output is in the wrong order - how can i fix this?

Tags: c, printf

I have a printf statement:

```
printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName, libNameCreationTime());
```

which gives me output in the format

```
[6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] Loaded library (C:/.../...)
```

but i need the output to be in the format

```
Loaded library (C:/.../...) [6-19-20 9:27:00 PM]
```

libNameCreationTime() is responsible for printing the time.
libName is the path (C:/.../...)

All this printf statement needs to do is print "Loaded library (path name) [creation time]. It prints the right things just in the wrong order.

Basically the time should be printed at the very end. I've been messing with format specifiers but to no avail. This should be a very simple fix but i can't figure it out.

Comment: What `libNameCreationTime()` returns?

Comment: `printf("(%s) Loaded library\n" ....` ?!? btw your code doesnt match the output

Comment: Can you create a small self-sufficient and runnable example? I think the code you provided is not showing the full picture.

Comment: are you sure of your code ? there is only **one** `%` in your format but two arguments after the format

Comment: The question was closed too fast. To have your behavior the function *libNameCreationTime* prints `[6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] ` so to have `Loaded library (C:/.../...) [6-19-20 9:27:00 PM]` do `printf("Loaded library (%s) ", libName); libNameCreationTime(); putchar('\n');` also allowing to have a 'normal' number of args in the `printf`. Currently your code is similar to `libNameCreationTime(); printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

> ```
>  printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName, libNameCreationTime());
> ```

you have only one '%' but two arguments after the format, because the first is a variable to have the output

> [6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] Loaded library (C:/.../...)

that means the function *libNameCreationTime* prints `[6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM]`

then to have

> Loaded library (C:/.../...) [6-19-20 9:27:00 PM]

do

```
 printf("Loaded library (%s) ", libName);
 libNameCreationTime();
 putchar('\n');
```

---

In fact the code

> ```
>  printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName, libNameCreationTime());
> ```

is equivalent to

```
 libNameCreationTime();
 printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName);
```

---

For instance :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int libNameCreationTime()
{
  fputs("[6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] ", stdout);
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  const char * libName = "C:/.../...";
  
  printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName, libNameCreationTime());
  
  puts("------------------------");
  
  libNameCreationTime();
  printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName);
  
  puts("------------------------");
  
  printf("Loaded library (%s) ", libName);
  libNameCreationTime();
  putchar('\n');
  
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
c.c: In function ‘main’:
c.c:13:10: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
   printf("Loaded library (%s)\n", libName, libNameCreationTime());
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
[6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] Loaded library (C:/.../...)
------------------------
[6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] Loaded library (C:/.../...)
------------------------
Loaded library (C:/.../...) [6-19-2020 9:27:00 PM] 
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the clear and concise examples. Your solution works. Thanks for helping me understand

Comment: My rookie colors are showing.. will remember for the future!